# OpenGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Since the latest android update came out, I haven't been very active with the new sdk. In fact, I don't know much about it. What I'm particularly interested in is of the changes that occurred, if any, regarding opengl. Did the implementation change? How would i go about writing a game in opengl for android with sdk 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the links broschb posted you can also have a look at this opengl-es I wrote for Android 2 months ago:

http://www.ruibm.com/?p=263

Answer (score 0):

I would start here http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0-highlights.html, at a quick glance it doesn't look like anything related to opengl changed.

1.6 did include some enhancement to opengl http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/now-available-android-16-ndk.html